# PHP displaying field name and field data in tow columns

Tags: php

I have a small script that outputs the results of a query but it displays it in two rows, the first row contains the field name and the second row contains the field data.

What I am trying to do is display it as the first column with all the field names and the second column with all the field data.

The code below produces a layout like:

Fieldname  Fieldname  Fieldname

Fielddata  Fieldname  Fieldname

Is there a way I can produce a layout like:

Fieldname Fielddata

Fieldname Fielddata

Fieldname Fielddata

The code I have:

```
            $numFields = mysql_num_fields($FailedList);

            echo "<table>";
                for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
                {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo mysql_field_name($FailedList,$i);
                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($FailedList)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
                    {
                        echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
                    }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                echo "</table>";
```

Any help would be great,

Regards,

DCJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($FailedList);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($row as $k => $v)
    echo '<tr><td>'.$k.'</td><td>'.$v.'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou both for your replies, the reply from "swordofpain worked better for me. But thanks "Sager"

Answer (score 0):

This might be true,

```
        echo "<table>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
            {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo mysql_field_name($FailedList,$i);
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($FailedList)) {

            for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
                {
                    echo "<tr><td>$row[$i]</td></tr>";
                }

                }
            echo "</table>";
```

but better is use `mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result); while{ // your data; }`